# How do i save raw php code to database or text file for sending email message?

Tags: php

Well, In admin panel I'm going to create a custom Email Template. For example... 1) Registration Confirmation 2) Forgot Password etc...

Now let's talk about Registration Confirmation.

After successfully register I'm (admin) sending a confirmation email which I want to edit from admin panel. So my confirmation text is look like this which I save it as .tpt file :

**Confirmation text with php code:**

```
<p>Hello $fname $lname, Thanks for your registration in our site Following is your login info.<p/>
<p>Username : <strong>$email</strong> <br/> Password : <strong>$password</strong> </p> <br/> Please click on the link to active your acccount. <a 
href='www.//mysite.com/activeAccount.php?code=$key&gonona=$userid'>Active My Account</a> </p>
<p>Thank You.<br/>Support Team <br/>www.//mysite.com/</p>";
```

In Register.php file I just call this .tpt file when I sending a email message using...

```
$message = file_get_contents("templates/email_verification.tpt", true);
```

In admin panel when I want to edit it I just call it with `$file_content = file_get_contents($file);` function in html textarea field.

**So what I want is...**
When I send the confirmation message from Register.php page I got text with php code(variable e.g. $fname, $lname) in my email addresss which I don't want. It's should be all plain text. It's should be get the php variable (e. g. `$fname, $lname, $email, $password, $key, $userid` etc..) value from Register.php page and send it to email address...

How can I do this ? any solution or Idea are Most Welcome :)

**Note:** Sorry for my bad English language and lack of Php knowledge.

Comment: maybe use `replace` function eg `str_replace($message,array("$user",...),array($user,...))`

Comment: Basically the idea would be : 1) Load your file content into a variable 2) perform string replacement on that string to replace variables/placeholders (you may want to use another variable format in your file though) by their values.

Comment: @Valerij then is it show all plain in to the email ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't necessarily have to save php variables in your template.

You could also save a template like this:

```
Hello {{NAME}},
This is your password: {{PASSWORD}}
This is your email: {{EMAIL}}
```

This way your admin doesn't see weird PHP but a little bit more understandable template.

And when you load the template you can replace the words with your variables at the moment of loading templates.

```
$message = file_get_contents("templates/email_verification.tpt", true);
$search = array(
    '{{NAME}}',
    '{{EMAIL}}',
    '{{PASSWORD}}',
);
$replace = array(
    $fname,
    $femail,
    $fpassword,
);
$message = str_replace($search, $replace, $message);
```

Personally I also like to use [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

```
$trans = array(
    "{{NAME}}" => $fname,
    "{{EMAIL}}" => $femail,
    "{{PASSWORD}}" =>  $fpassword
);
$message = strtr($message, $trans);
```

The reason why `strtr()` could be better is if i would enter the following data in form:

- name : {{PASSWORD}}
- email:test@test.com
- password:foobar

With `str_replace()` If I would enter my name as `{{PASSWORD}}` the incorrect result would be this:

```
Hello foobar,
This is your password: foobar
This is your email: test@test.com
```

This is because `str_replace` replaces the earlier replaced {{NAME}} with {{PASSWORD}} and again with the foobar!!

With `strtr()` te resul would be the foollowing (because it only replaces 1 time):

```
Hello {{PASSWORD}},
This is your password: foobar
This is your email: test@test.com
```

Which is correct in this case.

Comment: I also added some tips for `strtr()`

Comment: why you use `{{ }}` ?

Comment: Thanks for your tips Tim Dev but why you use `{{ }}` ?

Comment: I find it A) readable and B) there is a very very very small change the word will be used somewhere else in the template not as a variable, or actually used as value(which doesn't matter if you use `strtr()`).  You could also use other markup like `[name]`, or `@name`, `$name`, `!!^*name*^!!`. It doesn't actually matter ;)

Comment: Now Got it the puzzle :)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace text form `$message` with the values of your variables.

Try something like this (use `|` as special character at your template:

```
$variables = array(
    "|fname" => $fname,
    "|lname" => $lname,
    "|email" => $email,
    "|password" => $password
);

$message  = str_replace(array_keys($variables), array_values($variables), $message );
```

Edit: thanks @Valerij for your comment.

Comment: @babu keep in mind you dont need to iterate as `str_replace` accepts arrays for first 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

it should be like this:

```
Hello ' . $fname . ', ' . $lname . ',
```

Comment: hes not including the file but getting its context

Comment: I'm not sure if the first code in his question is in his PHP file or in his HTML file. anyway, my suggestion will work in the PHP file and Juan's answer will work in html file. so he's got answers for both.

Comment: its in a `tpt` file, and as hes using `file_get_contents` its not going through the php preprocessor, so no non of these are real answers

Comment: ah ok, however, he is asking why he is getting $fname, $lname instead of David Smith so he must be using PHP but in the wrong way and one of these two answers should help him.